# Increment a double value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this part of code in my system.

```
double countA = 0.00;  
double countB = 0.00; 


if (myrow.grade == "A") 
{ 
  countA += 1.00; 
}
else if (myrow.grade == "B") 
{
  countB += 1.00;  
}

countALabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countA);
countBLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countB);
```

The code is supposed to calculate how many student in my *examMarks* table that get "A" or "B" and display it using labels. However I keep getting `0` value even if there are students who get "A" and "B" in my table?

How do i get the increment value?

Comment: That would mean that your condition is not evaluated to true, are they really A, B or it could be a,b

Comment: why dont u use int? do you have 0.10 students?

Comment: here it means u want to display count of number of students?then why u using double data type for count?

Comment: Not sure why you have used double for count vars, probably you should be using int type as you are anyways increasing count by 1

Comment: Try using myrow.grade.ToUpper().Trim() == "A" in your code..!!

Comment: @Eppiey - Please show us your complete code (Where you created and initialize variable and so on). May be need to preserve some value during page postback.

Comment: indeed @AVD i also feel `myrow.grade` is string.Empty

Comment: What about using a GROUP BY [Grade] with a COUNT (in SQL or LINQ) ?

Comment: actually, i was using double so that i can calculate the percentage of A or B withou having converting int value to double first.

Comment: Debug...check if any condition is positive. Check with QuickWatch what result you have in `myrow.grade == "A"` statement when row grade is `A`.

Comment: @Vijay - indeed, there was empty spaces in the table.ur solution works. TQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit. I hope you won't mind.

```
  double countA= 0.00;
  double countB= 0.00;
  int test= 0;

  string entry= myrow.grade.Trim().ToUpper();

  switch(entry)
  {
      case "A":
      countA++;
      break;
      case "B":
      countB++;
      break;
      default:
      test++;
  }

  countALabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countA);     
  countBLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countB);
```

I added a 'test' variable that will tell you if the problem is within the code or outside the code. Also, try putting a breakpoint and watch the value of 'myrow.grade'. Goodluck!

Comment: it look less messy, sure i'll give it a try

Answer (score 3):

You have to place the first two lines and last two lines outside the loop:

```
double countA = 0.00;  
double countB = 0.00; 
foreach (MyRow myrow in rows)
{
    if (myrow.grade == "A") 
    {
        countA += 1.00;
    } else if (myrow.grade == "B") 
    {
        countB += 1.00;
    }
}
countALabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countA);
countBLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countB);
```

By having them all inside the loop you are always checking just the last grade, which is probably neither A nor B thus you get 0 in both.

Comment: for a better look (and easier programming) you can use a switch statement instead of all the if / else if statements. (also easier to ad grade C,D,E)

Comment: @Moonlight most elegant way IMO is creating `Dictionary<string, int>` that will count all grades but it's up to the OP here to decide. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that somehow the code in the IF statements is not executed.
The code += is indeed supposed to increment the value.

You might want to use the following code that ignores casing:

```
if (myrow.grade.Equals("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, there might be spaces inside your table values, so please use `Trim()` function as below in your code:

```
if(myrow.grade.ToUpper().Trim() == "A")
```

or as suggested by @Aphelion's answer including Trim():

```
if (myrow.grade.Trim().Equals("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check to see that your increments on countA and countB are actually executed. I suspect this may be an issue with using == instead of .equals on Strings.

Comment: Also, check if the cases match and if the string don't have any whitespace you need to trim first.